# Can ctypes run a dll function without knowing its name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I have some dll libraries that I'm trying to make, and I'm testing by loading other (checked as safe) dll's. As far as I've seen, you can run a function on a `_ = ctypes.CDLL()`, but is it possible for ctypes to tell you the name of a function/call it without knowing its name?

I tried what I could, which really is only looking to see if `ctypes.CDLL()` could tell you the loaded funcs/classes etc., but it doesn't say.

Comment: According to [\[Python.Docs\]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes): "*On Windows, some dlls export functions not by name but by ordinal. These functions can be accessed by indexing the dll object with the ordinal number*"

Comment: @CristiFati What does that mean? I should just do a `for i in range( . . . )` loop to in a `try:` block to find the function?

Comment: It's just an alternative to function names. But if you get such a function exported by ordinal it won't find its name. anyway the question seems a bit without sense (smells like an *XY Problem*). Why do you need this behavior? If you don't know what functions you want to call, what makes you think that you need a *.dll*, and if you load one that it's the correct one? Bottom line is if you want to (load and) call a function from a *.dll* you have to know its signature, and that is language agnostic.

Comment: @CristiFati Is there some other module for Python that can do this then? Because I do need this to work (since I'm trying to make a dll with some functions to do stuff Python can't) and I don't have the best memory so I need something that can tell me. Also (I'm dumb), what does language agnostic mean?

Comment: You need to know more than the name of the function.  You need to know the number and type of parameters to pass to the function as well.  "I'm trying to make a dll with some functions".  You would use the header file or source of the DLL as a reference and write your Python `ctypes` wrapper code.  You *can* list the function *names* exported by a DLL by using a tool like `dumpbin` in the Windows SDK, but that won't tell you the number and type of arguments.